# Problema con animación de fotos en UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Tengo un problema con la animación en la transición de fotos de un UIImageView. Necesito hacer que cada imagen que se muestre, tenga un efecto fade tanto al aparecer como al desaparecer. Actualmente, con el código que dejo debajo, solamente cambian las fotos pero sin efecto alguno.

```
import UIKit
import CoreImage
class InicioViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    let images = [UIImage(named: "portada-1.jpeg")!,
                  UIImage(named: "portada-2.jpeg")!,
                  UIImage(named: "portada-3.jpeg")!]

    let duracionAnimacion: TimeInterval = 15

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIView.transition(with: self.imageView, duration: duracionAnimacion, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            self.imageView.animationImages = self.images
            self.imageView.animationDuration = self.duracionAnimacion
            self.imageView.startAnimating()
            }, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una idea que se me ocurre es: Que tal  si pones cada imagen en un label podrias aplicar colores para el degrade sobre las imagenes:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
        self.label1.alpha = 1.0
        self.label2.alpha = 1.0
        self.label3.alpha = 1.0
    })
```